# Can I embed javascript as an xhtml attribute?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to update this code to call javascript in order to validate the url of my image.  This is PHP echoing xhtml with embedded javascript.

```
  echo "<img class = \"c\" src=\"$fav\" alt=\"\"\/><a name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";
```

This is what I have.  Will it work?

```
  echo "<img class = \"c\" src=\"<script type=\"text/javascript\">validate_fav($fav)</script>\" alt=\"\"\/><a name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it ok"? Will it work? Is it common? etc

Comment: Of course that won't work, is a `src` attribute usually HTML? It's a URL. So set it programatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is invalid XHTML. You end up setting the src to `<script type=` and then you have invalid markup.

You should do something like:

```
echo "<img id=\"theimg\" class = \"c\" src=\"$fav\" alt=\"\"\/><a name = \"a1\" class = \"b\" href = \"$ass_array[url]\">$ass_array[name]</a>";

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('theimg').setAttribute('src', validate_fave($fav));
</script>

<?php
```

Comment: Will setting the src attribute to itself cause the image to reload or only when it is set to a new image.

Comment: @Chris Aaker I'm not sure about all browsers, but in Chrome once the image is downloaded it won't redownload even if you set the src away and back again, unless you force the browser not to cache your images. I'm guessing other browsers are the same way.