# Will this Javascript snippet for image validation function?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this to validate images.  Basically it pulls the image on Id and sets the attribute to a url.  It relies on the onerror function to determine if the url is a valid image and if not resets the src attribute to a generic location.  Will this work?  It is based off of two other SO posts....[embedded javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054645/can-i-embed-javascript-as-an-xhtml-attribute) and [validation simplification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054576/how-do-i-validate-favicons-using-javascript).

// a is the url that is checked

```
function validate_fav(a)
  {
  var img=document.getElementById('theimg');
  document.getElementById('theimg').setAttribute('src', a);    
  img.onerror=function()
    {    
    a=d+'/favicon.ico';
    document.getElementById('theimg').setAttribute('src', a);
    }
  }
```

Comment: very redundant code, consider reusing the img variable, rather the access the DOM multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this link, wish I would have found this an hour ago

```
<img src="image.gif" onerror="src_to_generic()" />
```

at

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp)

Just call a function on the onerror that resets the src to a generic image.